AH01225 error reading request entity data while uploading files
Files of more than one GB fail to upload, which results in the following apache error.logs as:
[Mon May 13 06:33:27.604183 2024] [cgi:error] [pid 464] (-102)Unknown error -102: [client 10.140.204.235:59564] AH01225: Error reading request entity data, referer: https://10.105.105.84/cgi-bin/pages.cgi?title=cm_net
[Mon May 13 06:33:58.270188 2024] [cgi:error] [pid 462] (-102)Unknown error -102: [client 10.140.204.235:59579] AH01225: Error reading request entity data, referer: https://10.105.105.84/cgi-bin/pages.cgi?title=cm_net
[Mon May 13 06:34:28.962812 2024] [cgi:error] [pid 464] (-102)Unknown error -102: [client 10.140.204.235:59595] AH01225: Error reading request entity data, referer: https://10.105.105.84/cgi-bin/pages.cgi?title=cm_net
[Mon May 13 06:36:02.045791 2024] [core:debug] [pid 465] protocol.c(512): NULL bytes in header (47 bytes)
[Mon May 13 06:36:02.045822 2024] [core:debug] [pid 465] protocol.c(512): ...........V..p. 1603010200010001fc030356a2f370ad
[Mon May 13 06:36:02.045826 2024] [core:debug] [pid 465] protocol.c(512): 4...v..G1VI..... 34a18be676049247315649ce12b1bc0b
[Mon May 13 06:36:02.045828 2024] [core:debug] [pid 465] protocol.c(512): ..pS...+(.. ...  b21070535c071e2b28dcd72097a10a  
[Mon May 13 06:36:02.045840 2024] [core:debug] [pid 465] protocol.c(1450): [client 127.0.0.1:55540] AH00566: request failed: malformed request line
[Mon May 13 06:36:02.180668 2024] [core:debug] [pid 462] protocol.c(512): NULL bytes in header (96 bytes)

This was observed after upgrading httpd-2.4.41 to httpd-2.4.58.  Configurations in httpd.conf and apache.conf looks same in both versions. Files less than one GB upload without issue.
as per this doc and could be reason for this behavior:
https://downloads.apache.org/httpd/CHANGES_2.4

core: Change default value of LimitRequestBody from 0 (unlimited) to 1GB. [Eric Covener]

htaccess is below:
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_security.c>
    SecRuleEngine On
    SecRequestBodyAccess On
    SecRequestBodyLimit 2147483648
    SecRequestBodyNoFilesLimit 524288
    SecRequestBodyInMemoryLimit 524288
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_php7.c>
    php_value upload_max_filesize   15000M
    php_value post_max_size                 15001M
    php_value memory_limit  15000M
</IfModule>

and httpd.conf added below line:
LimitRequestBody 3000000000

Increased timeout to 600 in httpd.conf and apache2.conf and restarted apache. Still no luck.
Any suggestions?

For an update, it worked like charm after adding LimitRequestBody 3000000000
and Timeout 600 in /etc/apache2/apache.conf and restarting the apache. Note: File location may change as per your os
